# Why can't gdal save CRS information to GeoJSON?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, geojson

gdal fails to add CRS definitions to GeoJSON files in some cases.

Try this, for example, from any
linux terminal that has gdal installed:

```
# download the data
wget "http://giscience.tw.rpi.edu/rpi_group_projects/watershedders/data/gas_station.geojson"

# convert the downloaded file to shapefile format
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" gas_station.shp gas_station.geojson

# convert the shapefile back into geojson
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" gas_station2.geojson gas_station.shp
```

Both operations work fine, but the new geojson file
is missing a CRS. Here are the top 4 lines of 
`gas_station2.geojson`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
```

Line 3, usually reserved for the CRS, is empty.
Yet the correct CRS is saved in the Shapefile's .proj file:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
```

Note that gdal keeps CRS data when converting from GeoJSON to GeoJSON:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" gas_station3.geojson gas_station.geojson

# top lines of gas_station3:
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
```

This `"crs"` member is the same as the [original](http://giscience.tw.rpi.edu/rpi_group_projects/watershedders/data/gas_station.geojson).

Is this a bug in gdal?

A similar issue was [discussed](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/WriteOGR-to-GeoJSON-loses-CRS-td7586913.html)
on the R-sig-geo email list.

A related bug report was opened 2 years ago, but this is now closed: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4995

I've tried this on gdal 1.10.1 and 1.11.1.

Comment: At least that should not have any effect because your CRS seems to be the one that is the default in GeoJSON.

Comment: I can duplicate the results, but can't explain why. I don't see anything suspicious in the code.

Comment: In the latest standard GeoJSON is defined to always be in WGS84.

Comment: Well yes, but this is a draft https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-butler-geojson-04 and do not invalidate this http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html and GeoJSON data with CRS is quite common. When it comes to ogr2ogr, CRS is added into result by running the command with `-a_srs epsg:4326`or `-s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:4326`. I wouldn't call missing CRS as an error because urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84 is the default anyhow.